# What are the keyboard keys for regaining stamina in the chocobo race?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

In the PlayStation version of *Final Fantasy VII*, you could hold <kbd>R1</kbd> and <kbd>R2</kbd> to slowly restore stamina during races. What are the appropriate keys in the Windows version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you need to use the keys that the <kbd>L1</kbd> and <kbd>R1</kbd> of a PS controller would have used according to the links in the default case the following should work given you haven't changed the keys yet.

Try <kbd>Page Down</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>

[image: number pad]

[image: left keyboard]

**Methods to Change Controls** (either one works)

1. Access the in-game menu and navigate to config.
2. You can edit the `ff7inputcfg` file which is located in your game directory.

**Source for Controls:**

- http://www.finalfantasy7pc.com/game-info/game-controls/

**Sources for Racing:**

- http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/1169/t1485203-final-fantasy-7-chocobo-racing/
- http://steamcommunity.com/app/39140/discussions/0/846959362240484250/
- http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/130791-final-fantasy-vii/answers?qid=351187