# How do I play the piano in the Steam version of FFVII?

Tags: steam, final-fantasy-7

I'm playing through the piano in the steam version of FFVII and I'm in the Nibelheim flashback right after you leave Midgar. Cloud enters the mansion and finds a piano; it seems pretty obvious that I'm supposed to play the song I found on the piano in Tifa's house a little while back. However, when I hit 'insert' [SWITCH] for Re the screen flashes and I get a shrill noise, rather then a piano note. I tried remapping [SWITCH] to `G` but it does the same thing.

Without too many spoilers (I know far too many of them already, since this is such an old game) is playing the piano important, and is getting this odd noise normal when I hit [SWITCH]/Re

Edit: I'm trying to play the song, but nothing seems to happen when I finish it. Should I even be playing the song here?

Edit 2: The key works fine, as the note that is [SWITCH] + [Page Down] works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is the wrong piano to be playing that tune. Only Tifa's piano will give rewards for playing that song, not the mansion piano.

Secondly, yes, getting that noise on the mansion piano is normal. It actually serves as a hint. When you reach this point in the game (not in the flashback) you may find in the mansion a note that says to look:

> Behind the Ivory's short of tea and ray

The grammar makes me cringe, but indeed, this piano is short ti and re. And if you look behind this piano, you will find a certain piece of information.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to play the piano three times. the second and third time will grant you some great item in doing so. During the flashback you get 1 gil from doing it but you need to do it then to get the other items later.

The song you play does haves one note that sounds like it's odd but just finish the song (if you know it). [**Check out this question**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136295/what-are-the-keyboard-keys-for-regaining-stamina-in-the-chocobo-race) I asked in which someone showed a great image of keyboard controls. Since you aren't asking what the notes are for the song I won't tell you here for spoiler reasons.

Also check out [**this page**](http://www.finalfantasy7pc.com/game-info/game-controls/) and [**this page**](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_VII/Tifa%27s_piano) for more info and help about controls.

Comment: Crud, I played it several times and thought I'd gotten the song right, but didn't get a gil so I guess I'm screwed now. Someone else said I could move on.

Comment: Also as a note, those are the 1998 version controls, the Steam version redid them all for some reason.

Comment: When I played on the steam version I found the controls for the psx (trianlge, square, etc), converted them to the pc controls (insert, switch, etc) then finally to the steam controls. I suggest writing it down.

Comment: A nitpick: you don't get 1 gil in the flashback (you can't get gil now for something that happened years ago, after all.) You can get 1 gil when you play it when *not* in the flashback, though, but you have to get it right several times.